# Java; Не могу понять куда писать аргументы куда параметры метода

Tags: java

Необходимо выбрать максимальное число из массива.
Вроде се сделал по инструкции, но оно не работает.
Подскажите где именно ошибка и как именно должен выглядеть код.

public class Praktikum {

```
public static void main(String[] args) { // Главный метод - вход в программу
    double[] expenses = {1772.5, 367.0, 120.6, 2150.2, 874.0, 1.0, 1459.4}; // массив
    
    double maxExpense = findMaxExpense(maxExpense); // переменная которой приравнивается результат работы метода для расчета максимального значения
    System.out.println("Самая большая трата недели " + maxExpense); // отображения результата
}

private static double findMaxExpense(double[] expenses) { // Метод поиска максимального числа

    double maxExpense = 0;  // то с чего начинаем поиск максимального числа
    for (int i = 0; i < expenses.length; i++) {   // цикл
        if (expenses[i] > maxExpense) {
            maxExpense = expenses[i];  // приравниваем  каждое следующее большее число промежуточной переменной
        }
        return maxExpense; // возвращаем найденое максимальное число
    }

}
```

}

Comment: А компилировать пробовали перед обращением за подсказкой?  Есть такая штука - компилятор, который обычно ругается на неудобоваримый код, и предоставляет нужную информацию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. вынести return из цикла for, как написал Olegator36.
   получается у тебя после первой же итерации прекращается метод и возвращается значение maxExpense.
   и надо избегать одинаковых имён переменных, у тебя в мейне переменная maxExpense и в методе maxExpense
   2)`double maxExpense = findMaxExpense(maxExpense);`
   компилятор пишет что переменная может быть не инициализирована, плюс метод у тебя должен принимает массив, а ты туда примитив передаёшь. передавай массив expenses

   `double maxExpense = findMaxExpense(expenses);`

Comment: ПРЕОГРОМНЕЙШЕЕ Спасибо !!! 6 часов потратил на решение. Если бы не Вы...

Comment: @Victorioussword Victoriousswor в обучении мне очень помогла книга хорстманна и канал на ютубе alishev . советую ознакомиться

Answer (score 2):

Вынесите return из цикла for )))